# Mounting a copy of a managed disk on AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am trying to create a pod that uses an existing Managed Disk as the source for the disks that are mounted. I can attach the managed disk directly, but I can't make it work via PV and a PVC.

These are the files I'm using

**pvclaim.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: mongo-pvc
  annotations:
    volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-class: default
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 256Gi
  storageClassName: default
```

**pvdisk.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: mongo-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 256Gi
  storageClassName: default
  azureDisk:
      kind: Managed
      diskName: Mongo-Data-Test01
      fsType: xfs
      diskURI: /subscriptions/<SubId>/resourceGroups/Static-Staging-Disks-Centralus/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/Mongo-Data-Test01
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  claimRef:
    name: mongo-pvc
    namespace: default
```

**pvpod.yml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: adisk
spec:
containers:
  - image: nginx
    name: azure
    volumeMounts:
      - name: azuremount
        mountPath: /mnt/azure
volumes:
  - name: azuremount
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: mongo-pvc
```

The ultimate goal is to create a Statefulset that will deploy a cluster of Pods with the same Managed disk as the source for them all.

Any pointers would be appreciated!

**Updated to add**

The above will create a new disk for each instance (pod) that is launched. I am looking to create a new disk using the `createOption: fromImage`

So I'm looking for the underlying Azure infrastructure to create a copy of the existing managed disk, and then attach that to the pod(s) that are launched.

Comment: Did you see anschoewe's suggestion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48774021/how-to-configure-a-manually-provisioned-azure-managed-disk-to-use-as-a-kubernete

Comment: @huysmania I did, and most of the above is a direct copy of that exact piece of yml!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a conversation with one of the AKS developers, I was told that it is only possible to either attach an existing disk or to create a new, empty disk to AKS. It is unclear whether this will change in future.

Comment: have you found any documentation that describes this specific setup? I can do this using storage classes but I have a special encryption requirement that forces me to attach a managed disk to the actual AKS node, and then prepare it for use.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes provides access mode of 3 types for mounting Persistent Volumes to a Pod:

- ReadWriteOnce – the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node
- ReadOnlyMany – the volume can be mounted read-only by many nodes
- ReadWriteMany – the volume can be mounted as read-write by many nodes

In your case, if you want to mount one volume to many pods, you need to use `accessModes: ReadWriteMany`. So, you need to check, it is possible to use this mode for Azure.

For more information, you can go through that [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes)

Comment: I may need to update the question a little. I a mtalking about using the underlying Azure infrastructure to copy the disk before mounting it. so that each instance of a pod has its own dedicated attached disk mounted as ReadWriteOnce